# Url problems with jar

Tags: java, url, jar

I have a problem with my audio file path.

When I compile the project the audio sounds well but when I open the jar it gives me this error (I undestand the error but I can't see what I'm doing wrong...):

Sorry if its in spanish "No existe el archivo o el directorio" means "No such file or directory exists".

/home/user1/NetBeansProjects/project1/dist/project1.jar!/music/2.wav
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user1/NetBeansProjects/project1/dist/project1.jar!/music/2.wav (No existe el archivo o el directorio)
    at logic.AudioFilePlayer.run(AudioFilePlayer.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user1/NetBeansProjects/project1/dist/project1.jar!/music/2.wav (No existe el archivo o el directorio)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:164)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1179)
    at logic.AudioFilePlayer.run(AudioFilePlayer.java:36)

And here is the code:

```
boolean loop = true;
private final URL url = getClass().getResource("/music/2.wav");
private final String convertFilePath = url.toString();
String filePath = convertFilePath.substring(convertFilePath.lastIndexOf("file:") + 5);

@Override
public void run() {
    while (loop == true) {
        final File file = new File(filePath);
        System.out.println(filePath);
        try (final AudioInputStream in = getAudioInputStream(file)) {

            final AudioFormat outFormat = getOutFormat(in.getFormat());
            final Info info = new Info(SourceDataLine.class, outFormat);

            try (final SourceDataLine line
                    = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info)) {

                if (line != null) {
                    line.open(outFormat);
                    line.start();
                    stream(getAudioInputStream(outFormat, in), line);
                    line.drain();
                    line.stop();
                }
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}

private AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat) {
    final int ch = inFormat.getChannels();
    final float rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();
    return new AudioFormat(PCM_SIGNED, rate, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate, false);
}

private void stream(AudioInputStream in, SourceDataLine line)
        throws IOException {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int n = 0; n != -1; n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) {
        line.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the sound file bundled within the jar file? If so, you have to use other means to read the file.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove Yes, it is included as well as the images, they get bundled when the project is compiled in their own folder, but for some reason those work just fine except for the audio file :/

Comment: Are you also using the File object to load in the images? If the images are bundled within the jar, make sure you aren't accidentally loading identical images that also exist in your file system. If you are loading images correctly from the jar, then you know of the correct method you need to use to get a stream of the sound file from the jar.

Comment: You can't just convert the jarfile URL into a file URL (unless you're extracting the file, but it doesn't look like you're doing that from the stacktrace). Several libraries load files specifically based on the protocol. It's possible that your library doesn't support loading files from jars as well.

Comment: The thing is that I use the exactly the same for both but for some reason the image ones work well but the audio doesn't. And yes i tried to use the jar in another computer and it works just fine (except for the audio ofc)

Comment: @MxyL Mmm yeah probably maybe i could extract the audio from the jar and play it from there?

Comment: Actually have you tried just passing in the `url` variable directly instead of the `filePath` variable?

Comment: @mxyl that doesn't work not even with the compiler since it adds "file:". With the code posted atleast the compiler works...

Comment: The URL that is returned should begin with `file` if you are not running it from the jar, and `jar:file` if you are running from the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with JAR's, you should be handling `jar:file` URL's instead of manipulating it and trying to create a `File` object yourself. You should pass in the URL that you get from `getResource` directly to the constructor if it supports it.

```
// get the URL of the file as usual
URL url = getClass().getResource("/music/2.wav");

// get stream directly from URL, which could be a file or a jar:file
AudioInputStream in = getAudioInputStream(url);
```

If that doesn't work, and your library can take an input stream, you can try using [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and pass that to the appropriate constructors/methods.

Otherwise, you can try extracting the file to somewhere locally and then pass the path of that file.

My guess is that some libraries simply do not support loading files from a JAR when given a URL (with a `jar:file` protocol).

Comment: OH! you are right... I could try that... but for testing that it works i should both create one folder with the song in the src and another in the dist of my project right? To test both project/jar

Comment: That gaved me several ideas of what I can try, thanks a lot! AudioInputStream in = getAudioInputStream(url); <- Gaved the same error so I guess that input/output the song will make the trick.